How to get the ‘I Love Bees’ emblem and Nameplate in Halo Infinite?
I've seen players with the "I Love Bees" Emblem and Nameplate in Halo Infinite like this:


But I'm not sure how to obtain it? How can I unlock or obtain this specific Emblem and Nameplate?

Both were made available during the Halo's 20th anniversary event, where it could be obtained by connecting during the multiplayer Beta Test between November 15 and November 22 2021.
Both are still available to buy in the Exchange for 1000 Spartan Points.
